# Core Data object is saved without errors but data retrieve method don't show the saved results immediately

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm working on iOS application(Swift) which is using core data. In this application I use an object called `Audit` and once audit has completed I updated the `active` boolean property of that object to `false`. Following is the Audit object saving method. I used same method to both create and update cases.

```
 class func saveAudit(audit:AuditModel){
        let curntAudit = Utilities.auditDetails(auditId: Int(audit.auditId))
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        if curntAudit != nil {
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "AuditModel")
            fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "auditId == %i", curntAudit!.auditId)
            fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

            do {
                let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [AuditModel]
                if results!.count > 0 {
                    var auditModl = results?.first
                    auditModl!.date = audit.date
                    auditModl!.active = audit.active
                    auditModl!.critical = audit.critical
                    auditModl!.isNew = audit.isNew
                    auditModl!.pDepartments = audit.pDepartments
                    auditModl!.pImages = audit.pImages
                    auditModl!.sended = audit.sended
                    auditModl!.showNa = audit.showNa
                    auditModl!.abbreveation = audit.abbreveation
                    auditModl!.languages = audit.languages
                    auditModl!.templateId = audit.templateId
                    auditModl!.title = audit.title
                    auditModl!.conclusions = audit.conclusions
                    auditModl!.positiveAspects = audit.positiveAspects
                    auditModl!.idControl = audit.idControl
                    auditModl!.idDashboard = audit.idDashboard
                    auditModl!.locationId = audit.locationId
                    auditModl!.styleId = audit.styleId
                    auditModl!.totalComments = audit.styleId
                    auditModl!.totalImages = audit.styleId
                    auditModl!.totalQuestions = audit.styleId
                    auditModl!.majorAspects = audit.majorAspects
                }
            } catch  {
                print("failed")
            }
        } else {
            let auditEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "AuditModel", in: managedContext)
            let auditModl = NSManagedObject(entity: auditEntity!, insertInto: managedContext)
            auditModl.setValue(audit.date, forKey: "date")
            auditModl.setValue(audit.active, forKey: "active")
            auditModl.setValue(audit.critical, forKey: "critical")
            auditModl.setValue(audit.isNew, forKey: "isNew")
            auditModl.setValue(audit.pDepartments, forKey: "pDepartments")
            auditModl.setValue(audit.pImages, forKey: "pImages")
            auditModl.setValue(audit.sended, forKey: "sended")
            auditModl.setValue(audit.showNa, forKey: "showNa")
            auditModl.setValue(audit.abbreveation, forKey: "abbreveation")
            auditModl.setValue(audit.languages, forKey: "languages")
            auditModl.setValue(audit.templateId, forKey: "templateId")
            auditModl.setValue(audit.title, forKey: "title")
            auditModl.setValue(audit.conclusions, forKey: "conclusions")
            auditModl.setValue(audit.auditId, forKey: "auditId")
            auditModl.setValue(audit.positiveAspects, forKey: "positiveAspects")
            auditModl.setValue(audit.idControl, forKey: "idControl")
            auditModl.setValue(audit.idDashboard, forKey: "idDashboard")
            auditModl.setValue(audit.locationId, forKey: "locationId")
            auditModl.setValue(audit.styleId, forKey: "styleId")
            auditModl.setValue(audit.totalComments, forKey: "totalComments")
            auditModl.setValue(audit.totalImages, forKey: "totalImages")
            auditModl.setValue(audit.totalQuestions, forKey: "totalQuestions")
            auditModl.setValue(audit.majorAspects, forKey: "majorAspects")
        }

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Couldn't save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

Right after updating the `active` flag, User will redirect to the separated screen and that screen will shows the list of all the audit objects which is `active == false`. Following is the data retrieving  method.

```
 class func finishedAudits() -> [AuditModel]? {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return nil}
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "AuditModel")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "active == NO")
        fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        do {
            let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            return results as! [AuditModel]
        } catch  {
            print("failed")
            return nil
        }
    }
```

Problem is the recently updated object is not retrieve by the above method. Once I re-run the application then only above method shows the recently updated object. I have tried to fix this different ways but non of them were working. Is anybody knows what's wrong here? creating `managedContext` object in every method causes to this problem?

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return }
let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
```

Can anyone help me with this? I'm stuck with this since few days now.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You are not setting active to false, you are setting it to the value of the object passed to the save method. Also note that when calling ` try managedContext.save()` you are saving not only the new object `auditModl` but also `audit` if it has any changes.

Comment: Yes that's what exactly I'm trying to do. Before calling the saveAudit(audit:AuditModel) method I'm updating the active flag of the audit object outside this method and passes that updated object to this method

Answer (score 0):

Fetch requests only fire once. They are not updated dynamically when objects are inserted.

Use a breakpoint to see if your fetch method is actually being run before the insert is performed, possibly by some other action or method, or if it is not actually run again after the insert.

To simply this process, I would recommend using a FetchedResultsController which monitors the database for changes that would be returned by its corresponding fetch request. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller